# Powershell import-CSV missing elements

Tags: powershell

I have an CSV file with 300 users Name.  I need to Remove the Journal Rules for these users in Microsoft Exchange 2007 SP3 using the Powershell.

I created a PS1 file with the following info:

import-csv C:\Journal.txt Remove-JournalRule

The CSV file has one column heading is "Name".  My script looks too simple. Can you tell me what is missing?  Thanks

Comment: how about is this correct? Import-CSV = "E:\Journal\Journal-users.csv" foreach ($user in Import-csv) {Remove-JournalRule $user -confirm:$false}

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the csv had a column with the header RuleID from which you were pulling the identity for the rule:

```
$JournalCSV = Import-CSV "E:\Journal\Journal-users.csv" 
foreach ($JournalEntry in $JournalCSV) {
    Remove-JournalRule $JournalEntry.RuleID -confirm:$false
}
```